# xcode: iOS 10 and below simulators in xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

How to install iOS 10 and below simulators in Xcode 11.2? I dont find any way of install iOS 10 and below simulators. Please help.

The deployment target is set to iOS 9 and above.

Comment: what is last version of simulator in component?

Comment: 12.2 @chiragshah

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the [Xcode release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes?language=objc), in the Simulator section:

> Xcode no longer creates every available iOS simulator device by
>   default. Instead a set of the most commonly used devices are created.
>   To create other devices — or multiple instances of a device — open the
>   Devices window, select Simulators, click the + button, enter a name,
>   and select the relevant device type and OS version. In Terminal,
>   execute the xcrun simctl create   
>   command, for example xcrun simctl create "My iPhone 7" "iPhone 7"
>   iOS13.0. (49428617)

Comment: I was specifically asking for iOS 10.0 simulator in Xcode 11.2 @OoiBP